# How can I exclude zeros when finding a frequency and seperate into 4 categories

Tags: r

I have a data frame `data.2016` and am trying to find the frequency in which "DIPL" occurs (excluding zero), "DIPL" is the number of a worms parasite found in the a fish.

Data looks something like this:

```
data.2016

Site  DIPL
1        0
1        1
1        1
2        6
2        8
2        1
2        1
3        0
3        0
3        0
4        1258
4        501
```

I want to output to look like this:

```
Site   freq
1        2
2        4
3        0
4        2
```

From this I can interpret, out of the 3 fish found in site #1 (from the data frame), 2 of them had worm parasites.

I've tried

```
aggregate(DIPL~Site, data=data.2016, frequency) #and get:
  Site DIPL
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    3    1
4    4    1
```

Is there a way to count the number of fish with worms from the `DIPL` column (meaning the value in the column is higher than zero) per site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a custom function that removes the zeros.

```
aggregate(DIPL ~ Site, data.2016, function(x) length(x[x != 0])) # or sum(x != 0)
#   Site DIPL
# 1    1    2
# 2    2    4
# 3    3    0
# 4    4    2
```

Another option would be to temporarily transform the `DIPL` column then just take the sum.

```
aggregate(DIPL ~ Site, transform(data.2016, DIPL = DIPL != 0), sum)
#   Site DIPL
# 1    1    2
# 2    2    4
# 3    3    0
# 4    4    2
```

`xtabs()` is fun too ...

```
xtabs(DIPL ~ Site, transform(data.2016, DIPL = DIPL != 0))
# Site
# 1 2 3 4 
# 2 4 0 2
```

By the way, `frequency` is for use on time-series data.

Data:

```
data.2016 <- structure(list(Site = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L), DIPL = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1258L, 
501L)), .Names = c("Site", "DIPL"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Might something like this be what you're looking for?

```
# first some fake data 
site <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B")
numworms <- c(1,0,3,0,0,42)
data.frame(site,numworms)
  site numworms
1    A        1
2    A        0
3    A        3
4    B        0
5    B        0
6    B       42

tapply(numworms, site, function(x) sum(x>0))
A B 
2 1
```

Comment: ah, with your data, something like `with(data.2016, tapply(DIPL, Site, function(x) sum(x>0)))`